# Autocomplete usernames when TAB is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I'm working on a "autocomplete usernames when TAB is pressed" feature.

I've been able to detect `@` and to search in a username list.

How to perform the autocompletion now, with a different matching username each time we press <kbd>TAB</kbd> ?

```js
var userlist = ['bonjour', 'bleuet', 'bonobo', 'coucou'];

function getCaretPosition(ctrl) {
    var start, end;
    if (ctrl.setSelectionRange) {
        start = ctrl.selectionStart;
        end = ctrl.selectionEnd;
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        var range = document.selection.createRange();
        start = 0 - range.duplicate().moveStart('character', -100000);
        end = start + range.text.length;
    }
    return {
        start: start,
        end: end
    }
}

$('#writing').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 9) {
      var caret = getCaretPosition(this);
      var word = /\S+$/.exec(this.value.slice(0, this.value.indexOf(' ',caret.end)));
      word = word ? word[0] : null;
      if (word.charAt(0) === '@') 
        alert(userlist.filter((x) => x.indexOf(word.slice(1)) === 0));
      e.preventDefault();  
      return false;
    }

    });
```

```css
#writing { width: 500px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="writing">Hello @b what's up? hello @you as well... Type @b and then "TAB" key it should autocomplete usernames 
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very basic example that works in modern browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge):

```js
const users = ['asdasd', 'fgsfds', 'Foobar']
const input = document.getElementById('input')
const patt = /\S+$/

input.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.key !== 'Tab') {
    return
  }
  e.preventDefault()
  const start = input.selectionStart
  const seg = input.value.slice(0, start)
  const match = (seg.match(patt) || [])[0]
  if (!match) {
    return
  }
  const idx = users.findIndex(x => x.startsWith(match))
  if (idx < 0) {
    return
  }
  const replace = users[users[idx] === match ? (idx + 1) % users.length : idx]
  const newSeg = seg.replace(patt, replace)
  input.value = newSeg + input.value.slice(start)
  input.setSelectionRange(newSeg.length, newSeg.length)
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" size="50" value="bla asd bla fgs">
```

It cycles through the names and works at any point in the line. Support for older browsers can be added with Babel and es6-shim.

Comment: For future reference, as suggsted by @slikts, `const patt = /\b@?(\S+)$/;` will make both `user + TAB` or `@user + TAB` work. Thanks one million times to him!

Comment: To make it work with more browsers, it's possible to copy/paste the code into http://babeljs.io/

Comment: You should probably just have Babel as part of your build step.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution for your issue:

I used .on() to bind keydown to textbox, rather than keypress.

```js
var userlist = ['bonjour', 'bleuet', 'bonobo', 'coucou'];

function getCaretPosition(ctrl) {
    var start, end;
    if (ctrl.setSelectionRange) {
        start = ctrl.selectionStart;
        end = ctrl.selectionEnd;
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        var range = document.selection.createRange();
        start = 0 - range.duplicate().moveStart('character', -100000);
        end = start + range.text.length;
    }
    return {
        start: start,
        end: end
    }
}

$('#writing').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 9) {
      var caret = getCaretPosition(this);
      var word = /\S+$/.exec(this.value.slice(0, this.value.indexOf(' ',caret.end)));
      word = word ? word[0] : null;
      if (word.charAt(0) === '@') 
        //alert(userlist.filter((x) => x.indexOf(word.slice(1)) === 0));
        var stringParts = $(this).val().split('@');
        var nameToInsert = userlist.filter((x) => x.indexOf(word.slice(1)) === 0)[0];
        var completeString = stringParts[0] + '@' + nameToInsert;
        $(this).val(completeString);
      e.preventDefault();  
      return false;
    }

    });
```

```css
#writing { width: 500px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="writing">Hello @b what's up? hello @you as well... Type @b and then "TAB" key it should autocomplete usernames 
</textarea>
```

Now it completes the name. But I would work on improving on the algorithm predicting the name.

Comment: There is bug when we press TAB with cursor after Hello @b : all the following words are erased.

Answer (score 1):

Replace keypress with keydown. Keypress doesn't fire when tab is pressed, I guess because tab gets input out of focus.

EDIT:

Not perfect, gets undefined sometimes, but you can work from here

EDIT: 
ok don't mind this, it's half done and @slikts solution is obviously better, made from scratch and all.

```js
var userlist = ['bonjour', 'bleuet', 'bonobo', 'coucou'];
    
    function getCaretPosition(ctrl) {
        var start, end;
        if (ctrl.setSelectionRange) {
            start = ctrl.selectionStart;
            end = ctrl.selectionEnd;
        } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
            var range = document.selection.createRange();
            start = 0 - range.duplicate().moveStart('character', -100000);
            end = start + range.text.length;
        }
        return {
            start: start,
            end: end
        }
    }
    function setCaretPosition(elem, caretPos, caretPosEnd) {
        caretPosEnd = caretPosEnd || caretPos;
        if(elem != null) {
            if(elem.createTextRange) {
                var range = elem.createTextRange();
                range.move('character', caretPos);
                range.select();
            }
            else {
                if(elem.selectionStart) {
                    elem.focus();
                    elem.setSelectionRange(caretPos, caretPosEnd);
                }
                else
                    elem.focus();
            }
        }
    }
function getIndexCloserTo(str, char, ref) {  
    if(str.indexOf(char) == -1) return false;
   //flip string and find char beggining from reference point
   var nstr = str.split("").reverse().join("");
   return str.length - 1 - nstr.indexOf(char, str.length - 1 - ref);
}
    var lastWordToMatch = "";
    var lastAddedWord = "";
    var lastIndexUsed = 0;
    $(document).ready( function() {
     $('#writing').keydown(function(e) {
     
          if (e.keyCode == 9) {
       var caret = getCaretPosition(this);
                //Get username input part, from the "@" closer to the cursor
                //to the position of the cursor
                var beginning = getIndexCloserTo(this.value, '@', caret.start);
                if( beginning !== false){
       var word = this.value.slice( beginning , caret.start);
       word = word ? word[0] : null;
       if (word.charAt(0) === '@'){ 
                    //Get array of names that match what is written after the @
        var usermatches = userlist.filter((x) => x.indexOf(word.slice(1)) === 0);
                    //Check if any matches were found
                    if( usermatches.length > 0 ){
                      //If the word is the same as last time, use the next match
          if( word == lastWordToMatch ){
                          //use mod to circle back to beginning of array
           index = (lastIndexUsed + 1 ) % usermatches.length;
           lastIndexUsed = index;
          } else {
                        //otherwise get first match
           index = 0; 
           lastWordToMatch = word;
          }
                      var text = this.value;
                      //Remove @
                      word = word.slice(1);
                      //replace the portion of the word written by the user plus the 
                      //word added by autocompletion, with the match
          $(this).val(text.replace(word+lastAddedWord, usermatches[index]) );
                      //save the replacement for the previous step, without the user input
                      //just what autocompetion added
                      lastAddedWord = usermatches[index].replace(word, '');
                      //put cursor back where it was
          setCaretPosition(this,caret.start);  
                    }
       }
                 }
        e.preventDefault();  
        return false;
      }
    
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="writing">Hello @b what's up? hello @you as well... Type @b and then "TAB" key it should autocomplete usernames 
</textarea>
```

Comment: Sorry, the question is how to do the actual autocompletion (i.e. automatically replace the beginning of username by a username in the list).

Comment: What do you need exactly? a dropdown with all the names? or to put the first name match in the input and then put the cursor on the last character written by the user?

Comment: `put the first name match in the input and then put the cursor on the last character written by the user` exactly, and then if TAB is pressed again, the next matching  (no dropdown) @mikepa88.

Comment: Nice @mikepa88 ! Two little bugs: 1) try "@zz" then `TAB`, it displays "undefined" => it should do nothing   2) if there are many words in the textarea such as `Hello @b what's up? hello @you as well` : if you click on @b then `TAB` : it deletes *all the text*, and just writes a username. How to insert the username at the right place instead?

Comment: use '$(this).val( $(this).val().replace(word, "@"+usermatches[index] )' , or something similar, to replace the word instead of the whole content. For the undefined issue, check if the userlist.filter returns an empty result and in that case don't do anything